# Quasar export table to json

Tags: json, quasar-framework, quasar

I am studying quasar at the moment, and I want to know how to export a table to JSon. I have data in JSonimported and I want to get output in JSon too.

Now I'm using JSON.stringify to get data of my table, but that gives all data in a single line in JSon.

Here's a piece of my code in quasar :

`exportTable() { const status = exportFile('table.json',  JSON.stringify(this.data), 'text/json')}`

and it gives me :

```
[{"Name":"xxx","Adress":"xxx","Zip code":"xxx"},{"Name":"yyy","Adress":"yyy","Zip code":"yyy"}]
```

What I want to output :

```
[{
"Name":"xxx",
"Adress":"xxx",
"Zip code":"xxx"
},
{
"Name":"yyy",
"Adress":"yyy",
"Zip code":"yyy"
}]
```

How can I get this ?

Comment: you can use JSON.parse(variableNameOfStringifyJSON)

Comment: your question is not explaning much kindly explain more and make it simple

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly, you want to use:

```
JSON.stringify(this.data, null, 4)
```

Where the last argument (4) is the spacing you desire.

You can have a look at [JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) official documentation

```js
const data = [{"Name":"xxx","Adress":"xxx","Zip code":"xxx"},{"Name":"yyy","Adress":"yyy","Zip code":"yyy"}]

console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, 4))
```